# How can we define an RNN - LSTM neural network with multiple output for the input at time "t"?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to construct a RNN to predict the possibility of a player playing the match along with the runs score and wickets taken by the player.I would use a LSTM so that performance in current match would influence player's future selection.

> **Architecture summary:**

**Input features:** Match details - Venue, teams involved, team batting first

**Input samples:** Player roster of both teams.

**Output:**

1. Discrete: Binary: Did the player play.
2. Discrete: Wickets taken.
3. Continous: Runs scored.
4. Continous: Balls bowled.

> **Question:**

1. Most often RNN uses "Softmax" or"MSE" in the final layers to process "a" from LSTM -providing only a single variable "Y" as output. But here there are four dependant variables( 2 Discrete and 2 Continuous). Is it possible to stitch together all four as output variables?
2. If yes, how do we handle mix of continuous and discrete outputs with loss function?

(Though the output from LSTM "a" has multiple features and carries the information to the next time-slot, we need multiple features at output for training based on the ground-truth)

Answer (score 0):

You just do it. Without more detail on the software (if any) in use it is hard to give more detasmail

The output of the LSTM unit is at every times step on of the hidden layers of your network

You can then input it in to 4 output layers.

1 sigmoid 
2 i'ld messarfound wuth this abit. Maybe 4x sigmoid(4 wickets to an innnings right?) Or relu4
3,4 linear (squarijng it is as lso an option,e or relu)

For training purposes your loss function is the sum of your 4 individual  losses.
Since f they were all MSE you could concatenat your 4 outputs before calculating the loss.

But sincd the first is cross-entropy (for a decision sigmoid) yould calculate seperately and sum.
You can still concatenate them after to have a output vector